# Used mkfs.ext4 on wrong partiton while installing arch linux

Tags: archlinux, partition

As the title says, while installing arch linux, I accidently used the mkfs.ext4 command on the 'Microsoft Reserved' partition. Windows still runs, but I'm afraid of any future problems. Does this need any fixing, and if yes, how should I go about it?

Comment: Please note  that Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Check out Super User, do a search and read the help section before posting if there isn't anything relating to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

this command `mkfs.ext` will format your partition...So you can not restore this partition now,but there is no data in this partition...

wikipedia:

> (MSR) is a partition of a data storage device, which is created simply to reserve a portion of disk space for possible subsequent use by a Windows operating system installed on a separate partition.

see more:[ms-wiki-msr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn640535(v=vs.85).aspx#gpt_faq_what_is_msr)

this partition is unneccessary.your windows has no problem.

---

Of course, you can creat a msr,`create partition msr size=256M`。

some tools (eg. diskpart ..and.I haven't used win for a long time.I remember that windows has a disk-magament ) can help you to fixed this partition.

Answer (score 0):

No need to fix anything. This partition is unformatted and occasionally use by Windows to make operations with the partition. Some disk drivers are also using it to make recovery in the case of power failure faster.
You can easily drop/create it.
Usual size for <16Gb is 32Mb and >16Gb disk is 128Mb. On Windows 10 it is just 16Mb